# Breakpoint on search results in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to debug my program by putting a breakpoint on the search results.

As I have ~1000 matches I am hoping that there is a simple and fast way to do this.

Comment: If you are looking for  variable references, check if data breakpoint is what you need.

Comment: After a bit of research, I don't think those will suit what I want, it will narrow it down slightly though. I am looking for when and where my program calls a certain method of which there are many other ones named the same thing but for different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is generate the `Eclipse` xml file containing all the breakpoints you need.

just right click on the break points tab and choose `Expoert Breakpoints...`

save the file, edit it programmatically, and import it back.

A **Simple** example for writing such file:

```
    Map<String, Integer> breakPointsLocation = new HashMap<>();
    // some logic to fill this hashmap based on your search results (you can use grep)

    // header
    System.out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    System.out.println("<breakpoints>");
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry: breakPointsLocation.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("<breakpoint enabled=\"true\" persistant=\"true\" registered=\"true\">");
        System.out.println("<resource path=\"" + entry.getKey() + "\" type=\"1\"/>");
        System.out.println("<marker charStart=\"1317\" lineNumber=\"" + entry.getValue() + "\" type=\"org.eclipse.jdt.debug.javaLineBreakpointMarker\">");
        System.out.println("<attrib name=\"charStart\" value=\"1317\"/>");
        // add some more attrbiutes here
        System.out.println("</marker>");
        System.out.println("</breakpoint>");
    } 

    //footer
    System.out.println("</breakpoints>");
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this seems harder to do then clicking on every search result and then double clicking to put a breakpoint.

Comment: for 10 breakpoints maybe. for a 1000 defiantly not. (editing the file will of course should not be done manually)

Comment: okay that and the grep thing seems to be useful, I'll have to go learn about grep now. Shame eclipse doesn't have what I wanted built in.